# Creating a dataframe from a dict where keys are tuples and values are lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, split

Assuming that, we have the following dictionary, with keys as tuples and values as lists:

```
dict_temp  = {('first', 'line'): [1, 2], ('second', 'line'): [1, 21, 11]}
```

I'd like to create a dataframe with 2+n columns: Col1 and Col2 from tuples, and Col3, Col4, ... from each element in lists which should look like this:

```
    0       1       2   3   4
0   first   line    1   2   NaN
1   second  line    1   21  11.0
```

Hence, I need to split the column with lists as well. What I have done is:

```
dict_temp  = {('first', 'line'): [1, 2], ('second', 'line'): [1, 21, 11]}
df_left    = pd.Series(dict_temp).reset_index()
df_right   = pd.DataFrame(df_left[0].tolist())
df_left    = df_left.drop([0], axis=1) # Drop column
df         = pd.concat([df_left, df_right], axis=1)
#df.columns = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
df
```

The output is:

```
level_0 level_1     0   1   2
0   first   line    1   2   NaN
1   second  line    1   21  11.0
```

Although I have handled the issue inspiring by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012099/creating-a-dataframe-from-a-dict-where-keys-are-tuples) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns), I think there should be a much better pythonic way to cope with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this `list` comprehension with list unpacking, then just simply convert it to a `DataFrame`:

```
lst = [[*k] + v for k, v in dict_temp.items()]
print(pd.DataFrame(lst))
```

Output:

```
        0     1  2   3     4
0   first  line  1   2   NaN
1  second  line  1  21  11.0
```

Comment: Alternatively `list(k) + v` or `itertools.chain(k, v)`.

Comment: Yeap @timgeb, they are also other good options :)

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks a lot. Marked as an answer as well.